# ayncio timeout in wait method explain

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

```
>>> import asyncio
>>> help(asyncio.wait)
```

..

```
Help on function wait in module asyncio.tasks:

wait(fs, *, loop=None, timeout=None, return_when='ALL_COMPLETED')
    Wait for the Futures and coroutines given by fs to complete.

    Coroutines will be wrapped in Tasks.

    Returns two sets of Future: (done, pending).

    Usage:

        done, pending = yield from asyncio.wait(fs)

    Note: This does not raise TimeoutError! Futures that aren't done
    when the timeout occurs are returned in the second set.
(END)
```

I dont quite understand last Note in this help (what is second set? is it pending/reprocessing set? how do I execute pending tasks and combine the results of both done and pending and then save in DB)

My problem: 
I'm using asyncio with aiohttp, have millions of urls , few of them might raise timeout error. I want to send them in a queue for reprocessing or it should take care by eventpool.

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
sem = asyncio.Semaphore(10)

def process_data(url):
    with (yield from sem):
          response = yield from aiohttp.request('GET', url)
          print(response)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
c = asyncio.wait([process_data(url) for url in url_list], timeout=10)
loop.run_until_complete(c)
```

PS: I'm not using `wait_for` method.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the two sets from the help:

```
Returns two sets of Future: (done, pending).
```

The second set is the `pending` set, jobs that haven't finished within the timeout. It will return a tuple with two lists of futures, one of those that are done, and one that are still pending.

instead of:

```
c = asyncio.wait([process_data(url) for url in url_list], timeout=10)
loop.run_until_complete(c)
```

you should probably:

```
def dostuff():
    done, pending = yield from asyncio.wait([process_data(url) for url in url_list], timeout=10)

    # do something with pending

loop.run_until_complete(dostuff())
```

Here is more information:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.wait

Comment: I want to run pending tasks as well(asynchronously). how can I pass again in event_loop)?

Comment: @michael The pending tasks continue to execute after the `wait` timeout expires. They're not cancelled or aborted or anything like that. So there's no operation required to re-schedule them - they'll keep running in the background as long as you don't stop the event loop.